# flutter) Unable to add offset data to Firestore

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I made a simple draw function through Custom Paint.
When I draw a line, the coordinates of the line are saved as Offset. And I'm going to upload this Offset list to Firestore.

However, the Offset cannot be uploaded to Firestore

```
Invalid argument: Instance of 'Offset'
```

The Json data that I want to upload is as follows

```
I/flutter ( 6636): │  {
I/flutter ( 6636): │    "nickname": "dgh",
I/flutter ( 6636): │    "point": [
I/flutter ( 6636): │      "Offset(110.0, 265.4)",
I/flutter ( 6636): │      "Offset(110.5, 265.6)",
I/flutter ( 6636): │      "Offset(110.9, 266.1)",
I/flutter ( 6636): │      "Offset(111.3, 266.7)",
I/flutter ( 6636): │    ],
I/flutter ( 6636): │    "color": "MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xffff5722))",
I/flutter ( 6636): │    "width": 5.0
I/flutter ( 6636): │  }

// firebase upload code
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(COL_ROOMS)
    .doc(widget.roomKey)
    .collection(COL_DRAW) 
    .doc()
    // .set(currentLine!.toJson())
    // test
    .set({
      "name": "test",
      "offset": Offset(1, 1), // error!
    })
    .then((value) => logger.d("upload!"))
    .catchError((error) => logger.w(error));
```

How do I upload offset data to firestore?

Answer (score 0):

You cant push dart objects to firebase, you need to convert them to Map, it will be more useful, i recommend you do the following

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(COL_ROOMS)
    .doc(widget.roomKey)
    .collection(COL_DRAW) 
    .doc()
    // .set(currentLine!.toJson())
    // test
    .set({
      "name": "test",
      "offset": {
        "dx": offset.dx,
        "dy": offset.dy,
      }, // error!
    })
    .then((value) => logger.d("upload!"))
    .catchError((error) => logger.w(error));
```

And when you retrieve it from firebase,

```
Offset(docSnapshot[‘dx’], docSnapshot[‘dy’]);
```